# Mysql find number of items using previous rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with hundreds of itemname

```
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   | date   | itemname | itemvalue |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-01 |    A     |    foo    |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-01 |    A     |    foo1   |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-02 |    B     |    bar    |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-02 |    B     |    bar1   |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-02 |    B     |    bar2   |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-03 |    A     |    foo2   |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-04 |    C     |    baz    |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-04 |    C     |    baz1   |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-05 |    B     |    bar3   |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-05 |    B     |    bar4   |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
```

I want the output to be

```
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   | date   | itemname | itemcount |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-01 |    A     |    2      |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-02 |    B     |    3      |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-03 |    A     |    3      | //1+2
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-04 |    C     |    2      |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |2020-05 |    B     |    5      | //2+3
   +--------+----------+-----------+
```

I tried `group by date, itemname` but that only gave me count per month. But the issue I'm having is how do I aggregate COUNT of itemvalue with previous month's itemvalue. For ex: in 2020-03, A value is a count of current(1)+previous months(2)

I'm using Mysql 5.7

Comment: This is common cumulative sum of counts over a group. For your version - use variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
select date, itemname, sum(count(*)) over (partition by itemname order by date) 
from t
group by date, itemname;
```

If your data is not very large, then a reasonable solution is a correlated subquery:

```
select di.*,
       (select count(*) from t where t.itemname = di.itemname and t.date <= di.date) running
from (select distinct date, itemname from t) di
```

Comment: I'm using 5.7 unfortunately

Comment: @AmitozDeol The second solution is version agnostic